# Default user ubuntu ec2 deleted Accidently

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I have accidently deleted the folder of defaut user ubuntu in my ec2 server , son whene i want to reconnecte to ssh , it gives me Permission denied (publickey).

Please my friends , really i'm blocked i have my data in this server and i can't find any way to access , please help me to solve this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/381970/consequences-of-deleted-key-pair-on-ec2-instance, which includes a link to a solution

Comment: My probleme is differente , i have deleted the folded of ubuntu user so now i'm unable to connecte in ssh it gives me  Permission denied (publickey)

Comment: I think the same [procedure](http://alestic.com/2011/02/ec2-fix-ebs-root) linked from that answer would still enable you to fix the deleted folder, by mounting the EBS volume on another instance and installing a public key. Or you could mount the volume on another instance and copy over the data. Assuming the root volume is EBS on your current instance.

Comment: i will try this procedure and reply you if ok , thanks a lot

Comment: no result , i have tryed this but no result

Comment: What do you mean by "no result"? How far did you get, and what part didn't work?

Comment: i didn't find the instance , it was deleted two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Stop the VM
2. In the EC2 console, under 'Actions' select 'View/Change User Data'
3. Enter the following, replacing the <username> with the desired username, and <publickey> with your public key from your computer

   > ```
   > #!/bin/bash 
   > useradd -ms /bin/bash <username>
   > mkdir /home/<username>/.ssh
   > echo '<publickey>' >> /home/<username>/.ssh/authorized_keys
   > chown -R <username>:<username> /home/<username>/.ssh
   > chown -R 600 /home/<username>/.ssh
   > ```
4. Save and start VM

Comment: thanks for your response , but i can't find my instance so it was deleted , i don't know how to restore this

Comment: If your EBS volume was deleted, there is no way of recovering it.

Comment: yes , that's what i found , thanks Craneum

Comment: Tried doing this. Still showing permission denied(public key).